# Check if session variable is defined

Tags: laravel

I need to count the number of views. I am using a session variable to avoid duplicate count. I need to check if session view_count isset  and then it is set to  false and increment the view  count

```
$currentPost = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
$comments =  \App\Comment::where('post_id',$currentPost->id)->get();

if(\Session::get('view_count')) {
    \Session::put('view_count', false);
    $currentPost->view_count = $currentPost->view_count + 1;
    $currentPost->save();
}
```

Comment: Your logic assumes that the user is viewing just a single post. How do you intend to handle view count for a different post or a new session is created by the same user?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
if (Session::has('your_key'))
{
  //your code here
}
```

#### Update answer

**Determining If An Item Exists In The Session**

To determine if an item is present in the session, you may use the has method. The has method returns true if the item is present and is not null:

```
if ($request->session()->has('users')) {
    //
}
```

To determine if an item is present in the session, even if its value is `null`, you may use the  `exists` method. The exists method returns true if the item is present:

```
if ($request->session()->exists('users')) {
    //
}
```

Comment: How to check if it has not  key

Comment: I explain more comfortable for you

Comment: $request  is not defined in the method

Comment: Use Request $request in controller function on top put  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to check whether a visitor has viewed a certain blog post, in which case, I'd probably do something like this.

```
$currentPost = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

// You should also probably set up your relationship with Comments
$comments = \App\Comment::where('post_id', $currentPost->id)->get();

if(! in_array($currentPost->id, session()->get('posts_viewed', []))) {
    session()->push('posts_viewed', $currentPost->id);

    // Your increment could also be simplified as follows 
    $currentPost->increment('view_count'); 
}
```

In your particular case, you will only be able to track whether the user has viewed one particular blog post. However, if you use an array and keep pushing viewed blog posts into it, you would be able to track views across many blog posts.